# Is the Angular orderBy documentation wrong? Or am I confused?

Tags: angularjs

I'm a bit confused after reading [Angular's orderBy documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/edit/master/src/ng/filter/orderBy.js):

> *In HTML Template Binding:*
>
> ```
>   {{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : array : expression : reverse}}`
> ```

This shows `orderBy` being used with 3 additional parameters (reverse is listed as optional), but I cannot find any examples of it being used with more than 2, and when it *is* 2, it appears to be in the form `{{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse}}` (ommitting `array`)

`array` is defined as "The array to sort.", but what does that make `orderBy_expression`? Shouldn't that be the array the filter acts upon?

I was actually going to [<kbd>Improve this doc</kbd>](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/edit/master/src/ng/filter/orderBy.js) and modify this (what I assume is a documentation error), but it wasn't at all clear to me what exactly was generating the template binding example (the docs are generated with JavaDoc-like comments right in the .js)

So, hopefully this is a valid SO question:

**Is the documentation in fact incorrect? Or am I somehow confused**

Comment: All the filters are documented in the same way, and they all seem wrong to me. I agree that the documentation seems incorrect.

Comment: The lines in the documentation seems to be generated the lines around 741-757 in this file https://github.com/m7r/grunt-ngdocs/blob/master/src/ngdoc.js although I'm not sure that's the exact code Angular uses.

Answer (score 0):

Filters have 2 modes of use. Programmatically, as a function, in which case the first param IS the array to act upon, and inline with | where the array on the left hand side is the array to act upon. So while it may not be immediately clear that is what is going on, the docs are not incorrect. Not saying it shouldn't be cleaned up. It would certainly be nicer if they showed both modes and clearly explained it. But I still stand by it being "correct." And, as Mikke pointed out, the current style of explanation IS consistent through the docs.

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter Your answer is true, but the documentation seems to indicate `orderBy` and `filter` should be given a total of 4 arguments.

Comment: The docs *do* provide examples of both modes of use. The *functional* method looks correct, but I still stand by that the *template* example seems incorrect. Unless you can do something like: `{{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : array : expression : reverse}}` (with __3__ additional parameters passed with `:`s), I would say that the documentation is definitely  __"incorrect"__